# Python invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
lastPosition = GPS.getActualPosition()
```

I m trying to compile a code which is about sending sms through telit module.

above statement is giving an error. I couldn't understand, GPS library is in the place where it's supposed to be and I imported it.

```
import SER
import MOD
import MDM
import GPS
```

syntaxError: invalid syntax

http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=20038
please help!!!

Comment: You would have to give more code. Chance is the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Please post the entire error, including traceback, as well as all the relevant code. "Invalid syntax" doesn't help us, because the syntax for the code you posted is fine.

Comment: http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=20038

john_melbourne    
PostPosted: Sun Feb 28, 2010 6:55 pm

here is the script , I just want to see how I can execute the phyton scripts. I uploaded and compiled another script but it was simple script. I m trying to execute this one. I want to take SMSes when I called the module.

http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/7357/errrx.png

here is the error

Comment: I deleted that gps thing and  put there an gpsacp string. then it gave an error again in SER.send statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post the OP referred to (in a comment -- **not** a great idea, @gheddo! edit your Q instead!), [here](http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=20038&start=0), has *exactly* this code (I'm copying and pasting only the two relevant lines):

```
def get_gps():
gpspos = GPS.getActualPosition() #Read GPS position
```

see the problem?  **No indentation** for the second line!  Therefore, a syntax error: function bodies (and other bodies of compound statements) **must** be indented in Python.

It was hardly necessary to send us reading that code, you know... the code's author, John Melbourne, in the **very next post** in this thread says, and I quote:

> Hi again Ryan,
>
> The forum software removed the
>   indentation from the Python script
>   that I listed in my earlier mail.
>
> You will need to re-indent the
>   function bodies, if and while
>   statements. See Flavio's original
>   source if your not sure how.

So that's exactly what you have to do -- re-indent the function bodies, `if` and `while` statements, and refer to Flavio Bernardotti's code if you need to for this purpose.

Also, in the future, I would strongly recommend you read at least **one** post later in a thread (if reading the whole thread is too much work for you...;-)...

Comment: =)   thanks a lot.

 it seems, the problem  was my poor vocabulary =)

thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps try some text editor with visible white-space? I've had pesky bugs like this until I turn on "Show Invisibles" in TextMate.

Comment: is there another way to  compile this script? I uploaded a sms_send script with txt extension and  I enabled it, then I used execscr command. it worked and sent me a text. but this procedure didnt work for this script or I couldnt make it . when I called the module, terminal shows RING  sign but SER libs and other parts dont work.